# Count the average number per day

Tags: python

I need to count the average number of data points that occur per day. But I can't figure out how to write the code for it in python. The data below is an example of what the data looks like. It is a ndarray and uses panda datetime. The expected values I would get is 01-01 would have 2 per day, 01-02 would have 1 per day, and 01-03 would have 2 per day.

```
   temp time =  array([ Timestamp('1979-01-01 11:21:59.904000'),
   Timestamp('1979-01-01 19:59:00.096000'),
   Timestamp('1979-01-02 07:54:59.904000'),
   Timestamp('1979-01-03 01:03:00'),
   Timestamp('1979-01-03 07:41:59.712000')]
```

Comment: `The data below is an example of what the data looks like`, could you be more precise? Is this a dataframe?

Comment: @yatu It's a ndarray

Comment: @yatu a panda datatime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas-grouper) with frequency set to `'D'`.

For example:

```
time = np.array([pd.Timestamp('1979-01-01 11:21:59.904000'),
   pd.Timestamp('1979-01-01 19:59:00.096000'),
   pd.Timestamp('1979-01-02 07:54:59.904000'),
   pd.Timestamp('1979-01-03 01:03:00'),
   pd.Timestamp('1979-01-03 07:41:59.712000')])

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':time})

print( df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='D'))['time'].count() )
```

Prints:

```
time
1979-01-01    2
1979-01-02    1
1979-01-03    2
Freq: D, Name: time, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @WoodyTheCoder The second `'time'` for what Series you want apply the `.count()` function.